# Is “herausquetschen” the right word for “to squeeze out”?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

I want to know if *herausquetschen* is the right word for *to squeeze out,* in the context of squeezing out a group of people, for example middle class families being squeezed out of private education.

Comment: Do you talk about ["squeezeing out" stakeholders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_out)? In this case, ["squeeze-out"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze-out) is used in german, too (as technical term for this particular legal phenomenon).

Comment: I would like to see a bit of context. Like "Insurer cutbacks squeeze patients out of high-end care"?

Comment: I meant  squeeze out in the context of middle class families being squeezed out of private education

Comment: What did you do to answer your question on a classical way (dictionary search)? Why wasn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the context i would prefer to use:

- verdrängen ([here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verdr%C3%A4ngen) you can find detailed explanation and Examples)

or

- [herausdrängen](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/herausdr%C3%A4ngen)
  / hinausdrängen

which may mean displace, push out or push away!

So as tofro (in his comment) and Hubert the verb "[drängen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dr%C3%A4ngen)" could also be used in this case especially in the form: "gedrängt werden" or "drängt aus etwas (hinaus/heraus)"

Comment: I second that. The original sentence from above would end up like "Angehörige von Mittelklassefamilien werden aus der ... gedrängt"

Comment: As a native Austrian I also support this answer.

Comment: "Herausdrängen" is excellent.

Comment: "Herausdrängen" does somehow imply you're pushing from the *outside*. "Hinausdrängen" might be even better, as it means you're pushing from the *inside*, which would fit better, depending on context.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

but you have to keep in mind a subtle difference between squeezing out toothpaste out of its tube and squeezing out people out of a stadium at the end of a game (in English as well an in German).

**Squeezing toothpaste out of a tube**

This is not done by the toothpaste itself. Somebody else has to do it:

> Gerald squeezed an inch of toothpaste out of the tube.
>   Gerald quetschte zweieinhalb Zentimeter Zahnpasta aus der Tube.

**Squeezing people out of the stadium**

Here the people are themselves performing the act of squeezing. My English is not good enough to decide if it is good style to say the next example-sentence. I think it is not, but I think it is grammatically correct English:

> The crowd squeezes itself out of the stadium.
>   Die Menge quetschte sich aus dem Stadion.

The German translation is definitely grammatically correct, but it is of bad style. It would be better to use *drängen*:

> Die Menge drängte aus dem Stadion.

Comment: I would like to add the note that _quetschen_ is stronger than _drängen_.

Comment: Also, if individuals (not groups) squeeze themselves through a narrow opening, _zwängen_ is more idiomatic. The appropriate preposition is _durch_ then and also applies to _quetschen_.

Comment: OP did not ask about *ausquetschen* but about *herausquetschen*.  Would that be correct for squeezing toothpaste?  Is herausquetschen correct for people squeezing out of a stadium when the speaker is speaking from inside the crowd?  Would it still be correct if the speaker is actually not in the situation but describing it from outside?

Comment: It depends on the prefix. *aus-* and *heraus-* describe a view from the outside, *hinaus-* describes a view from the inside.

Answer (score -1):

Das Wort *quetschen* und davon abgeleitete Wörter implizieren immer physische Gewalt oder Kraft. Sei es die Zahnpasta, die aus der Tube gequetscht wird, die Menschen, die sich aus dem Stadion quetschen (wie beispielhaft in den anderen Antworten genannt) oder metaphorisch jemand, der aus einer Person eine Antwort oder ein Geständnis herausquetscht. In jedem dieser Fälle wird unmittelbar echte oder metaphorische physische Gewalt angewendet.

Wenn es allerdings eher um abstraktere Vorgänge wie demographische Verdrängung geht, dann ist *quetschen* ungebräuchlich (außer ggf. in Fachsprache). In diesem Fall ist die Verwendung schwächerer Begriffe wie *Verdrängung* oder *Vertreibung* üblicher.

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed that at the time of writing I either didn't realize that the question was in English or that I was writing German. Happens sometimes when you're fluent in two languages. Since this whole StackExchange is all about German language, I think people are still able to read it, but here is an English version, just in case:

The word *quetschen* and derived words always imply physical force. Be it toothpaste which is squeezed out of the tube (*aus der Tube quetschen*), people who squeeze themselves out of a stadium (*aus dem Stadion (hinaus-)quetschen*) or, metaphorically, someone who squeezes an answer or a confession out of someone (*eine Antwort/ein Geständnis herausquetschen*). In all these cases there is immediate real or metaphorical physical force.

If you're talking about more abstract things, though, such as demographic squeeze-out, then *quetschen* is uncommon (except for maybe in technical language). In that case you should use weaker expressions such as *Verdrängung* or *Vertreibung* (meaning something more like *expulsion*).